# ComboBox KeyValuePair Binding WPF - Display Member

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding, keyvaluepair

i got a quick question about binding the `DisplayMember` of my `ComboBox`.
I have a list with a `KeyValuePair` for example:

1, Value1;
2, Value2;
3, Value3;

My `SelectedValuePath` is set to `Key` which is in my example "1".
Now i want my `DisplayMemberPath` to show "`Key` - `Value`" so for example the Textbox should show "1 - Value1".
Is that possible?
Thank's in advance!

Comment: Is this `ComboBox` supposed to be editable, e.g. `IsEditable="True"`?

Comment: Have you tried to do it?

Comment: The TextBox is not editable. I will try the solutions now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ComboBox` is not editable, you can create a `DataTemplate` for your key-value pairs.

```
<ComboBox ...>
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Run Text=" - "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do for instance so:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb1" ItemsSource="{Binding YourDictionary}" SelectedValuePath="Key">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="-"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cmb1}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way you can go is to use value converter:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb1" ItemsSource="{Binding YourDictionary}" SelectedValuePath="Key">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cmb1}"/>
```

```
public class KeyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is KeyValuePair<int, object> obj)//use your types here
        {
            return obj.Key.ToString() + "-" + obj.Value.ToString();
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("One way converter.");
    }
}
```